Google sign in with x-zumo-auth on flutter - Invalid Client Credentials
I need to have a google sign in in my Flutter app, then use an existing Azure API. Here's what I've got:
    User? user = await authService.signInWithGoogle();
    if (user != null) {
      await authService.authenticateWithAzure(user);
      // Navigate to the next page
    }

I can grab the idToken from the user result, and attempt to get the authorization_token from by calling my_endpoint/.auth/login/google`` {"id_token":"my token I just got from google"}, but get a "Invalid Client Credentials"
  Future<void> authenticateWithAzure(User user) async {
    final String? idToken = await user.getIdToken();

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("https://{mine}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google",), body: {'id_token' : idToken},  // Your Azure Function URL

    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Handle success
    } else {
      // Handle error
    }
  }

